# Is this patent still up to date?

Tags: patent-infringement

In reference to the patent: [US20160108345](https://www.google.com/patents/US20160108345)

Comment: can I patent it? or can I sell my own version of this product?

Comment: It is an application. It may or may not get granted. No you can't patent it.

Answer (score 0):

It has only 4 claims.  If your **version** does not depend upon these claims then you could begin the patent process if it is novel and not an obvious improvement.